# name.split based on multiple delimiters that have some of the same characters

Tags: vb.net

I have files coming into SFTP that are in the following format: 12345678_STLREPT. On occasion, they have two underscores instead of one. ie: 12345678__STLREPT. This throws my sorting program through a loop. So I attempted to do the top line of code below first, it threw an I/O exception. The second line I can make work if I add "__" as a delimiter, but my question is how does Name.Split work. I haven't been able to determine through my google searches if it stops at the first delimiter it finds in the string.

Basically, If it goes through the list of delimiters it would ideally match one of them, perform the split, then stop before performing the rest.
Example:
Say I have a file, named 1234__ASDF.PDF
Would the following code split it once for the first delimiter (__) then two more times for the second (_)? I feel like it would.

```
    fileInfo.Name.Split(New Char() {"__", "_", "-"})
```

Is anyone aware of a better solution to this problem?

Thank you,

Code, again. Top throws error, bottom is existing code:

```
    fileInfo = fileInfo.Name.Replace("__", "_")

    Dim a() As String = fileInfo.Name.Split(New Char() {"_", "-"})
```

Comment: You could split by single _ and just get the first and last element instead of the first and second element.

Comment: like this? after the split on _?

        string1 = a(0).Replace("_", "")
        string2 = a(1).Replace("_", "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be aware of your data types and what you are stuffing into them.  A `Char` holds a single character.  Trying to stuff two hyphens into a Char - for shame.

Next, be aware of your tools.  The [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) function accepts a [second parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_) that controls how empty elements should be handled.  It also includes overloads for accepting a [string array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_).

```
Dim fileParts As String() = fileInfo.Name.Split(
    New Char() {"_", "-"}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that Char is a single Char. For shame indeed!

The split options appears to work great. Thank you very much. My line of thinking was it would take "12345" as the first string and "_STLRPT" as the second. However it was saving the first, then the second string was null.